# Raspberry Pi 4 crashes at startup then boot loops

Tags: pi-4, boot, boot-issues, raspberry-pi-os

I have a raspberry 4 8GB model, tested with multiple power supplies, multiple SD cards, and even tried to boot from USB (both the 2.0 and 3.0 ports).

I also tried multiple images, the 64 and 32 bit normal and lite versions, I tried Arch (the official Arch Linux ARM release), and even tried a "gaming" image (one of those emulator things for the PI).

Nothing works and the PI breaks in around the same place every time.

The weird thing is that there is one specific thing that does work, the lite raspberry OS setup (the part where you choose the password, configure SSH, and all the other first time boot things). It's just everything else that doesn't even get to boot completely.

Is my PI just broken? Would the PI being "broken" even cause something like this?

Here's the last part of the log from a failed boot of the 64 bit lite OS:

```
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor kernel: brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: firmware: direct-loading firmware brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.raspberrypi,4-model-b.bin
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor kernel: brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: firmware: direct-loading firmware brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.raspberrypi,4-model-b.txt
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor kernel: brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: firmware: direct-loading firmware brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.raspberrypi,4-model-b.clm_blob
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: Mounted proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount - Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System.
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: modprobe@loop.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: Finished modprobe@loop.service - Load Kernel Module loop.
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: Finished systemd-binfmt.service - Set Up Additional Binary Formats.
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: Started systemd-rfkill.service - Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: Created slice system-bthelper.slice - Slice /system/bthelper.
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: dev-hugepages.mount - Huge Pages File System was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionPathExists=/sys/kernel/mm/hugepages).
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: apparmor.service - Load AppArmor profiles was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionSecurity=apparmor).
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: Starting modprobe@dm_mod.service - Load Kernel Module dm_mod...
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: Starting modprobe@efi_pstore.service - Load Kernel Module efi_pstore...
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor kernel: Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: Starting modprobe@loop.service - Load Kernel Module loop...
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: systemd-firstboot.service - First Boot Wizard was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionFirstBoot=yes).
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: first-boot-complete.target - First Boot Complete was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionFirstBoot=yes).
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: systemd-machine-id-commit.service - Commit a transient machine-id on disk was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionPathIsMountPoint=/etc/machine-id).
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: modprobe@dm_mod.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: Finished modprobe@dm_mod.service - Load Kernel Module dm_mod.
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: Finished systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service - Create Volatile Files and Directories.
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: Mounting run-rpc_pipefs.mount - RPC Pipe File System...
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: Starting systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization...
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: Starting systemd-update-utmp.service - Record System Boot/Shutdown in UTMP...
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: modprobe@efi_pstore.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: Finished modprobe@efi_pstore.service - Load Kernel Module efi_pstore.
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: modprobe@loop.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: Finished modprobe@loop.service - Load Kernel Module loop.
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: systemd-pstore.service - Platform Persistent Storage Archival was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionDirectoryNotEmpty=/sys/fs/pstore).
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: systemd-repart.service - Repartition Root Disk was skipped because no trigger condition checks were met.
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: Mounted run-rpc_pipefs.mount - RPC Pipe File System.
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: Reached target rpc_pipefs.target.
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: rpc-gssd.service - RPC security service for NFS client and server was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionPathExists=/etc/krb5.keytab).
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: Reached target nfs-client.target - NFS client services.
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: Reached target remote-fs-pre.target - Preparation for Remote File Systems.
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: Reached target remote-fs.target - Remote File Systems.
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4345/6 wl0: Nov  1 2021 00:37:25 version 7.45.241 (1a2f2fa CY) FWID 01-703fd60
Oct 10 05:57:47 raspi-tudor kernel: vc4-drm gpu: bound fe400000.hvs (ops vc4_hvs_ops [vc4])
Oct 10 05:57:48 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: Finished systemd-update-utmp.service - Record System Boot/Shutdown in UTMP.
Oct 10 05:57:48 raspi-tudor kernel: Registered IR keymap rc-cec
Oct 10 05:57:48 raspi-tudor kernel: rc rc0: vc4-hdmi-0 as /devices/platform/soc/fef00700.hdmi/rc/rc0
Oct 10 05:57:48 raspi-tudor kernel: input: vc4-hdmi-0 as /devices/platform/soc/fef00700.hdmi/rc/rc0/input0
Oct 10 05:57:48 raspi-tudor kernel: vc4-drm gpu: bound fef00700.hdmi (ops vc4_hdmi_ops [vc4])
Oct 10 05:57:48 raspi-tudor kernel: Registered IR keymap rc-cec
Oct 10 05:57:48 raspi-tudor kernel: rc rc1: vc4-hdmi-1 as /devices/platform/soc/fef05700.hdmi/rc/rc1
Oct 10 05:57:48 raspi-tudor kernel: input: vc4-hdmi-1 as /devices/platform/soc/fef05700.hdmi/rc/rc1/input1
Oct 10 05:57:48 raspi-tudor kernel: vc4-drm gpu: bound fef05700.hdmi (ops vc4_hdmi_ops [vc4])
Oct 10 05:57:48 raspi-tudor kernel: vc4-drm gpu: bound fe004000.txp (ops vc4_txp_ops [vc4])
Oct 10 05:57:48 raspi-tudor kernel: vc4-drm gpu: bound fe206000.pixelvalve (ops vc4_crtc_ops [vc4])
Oct 10 05:57:48 raspi-tudor kernel: vc4-drm gpu: bound fe207000.pixelvalve (ops vc4_crtc_ops [vc4])
Oct 10 05:57:48 raspi-tudor kernel: vc4-drm gpu: bound fe20a000.pixelvalve (ops vc4_crtc_ops [vc4])
Oct 10 05:57:48 raspi-tudor kernel: vc4-drm gpu: bound fe216000.pixelvalve (ops vc4_crtc_ops [vc4])
Oct 10 05:57:48 raspi-tudor kernel: vc4-drm gpu: bound fec12000.pixelvalve (ops vc4_crtc_ops [vc4])
Oct 10 05:57:48 raspi-tudor kernel: [drm] Initialized vc4 0.0.0 20140616 for gpu on minor 1
Oct 10 05:57:48 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: Finished networking.service - Raise network interfaces.
Oct 10 05:57:48 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: dev-hugepages.mount - Huge Pages File System was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionPathExists=/sys/kernel/mm/hugepages).
Oct 10 05:57:48 raspi-tudor systemd[1]: apparmor.service - Load AppArmor profiles was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionSecurity=apparmor).
```

Comment: These kind of scatter gun questions are unanswerable. Pick **ONE** OS; explain WHAT YOU actually DID. Preferably just use an OS (the default Raspberry Pi OS) - don't try to preconfigure it and install with monitor & keyboard.

Comment: I tried both preconfiguring it, and not preconfiguring it.
I just want to get the default raspberry OS to work, but I mentioned in my question that I tried everything I could. And yes, I did try with a monitor, and with a few resolutions and framerates.

Comment: Are you using the official 5.1V 3.0A power supply?

Comment: `the last part of the log` which log is that?

Comment: What are the specs on your power supply? Please to add this to your original post. Has the 5V 3A power supply been tested good with other Raspberry Pi's?

Comment: It's an official power supply, and I tried some non official ones as well.

Comment: I cleared the journal files on the SD card using my pc, then put it back in the PI, let it crah, and copied the only journal file that appeared (system.journal)

Comment: Is it the 5.1V 3.0A USB-C power supply?

Comment: Yes, it's the 5V 3A power supply. I also tried another that is supposedly more powerful, and one less powerful, but had no luck with either of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDMI cable had a short in it, that's why multiple monitors had the same problem as well, but having no other HDMI, I had to configure the image before flashing (in the imager) and connect with a ethernet cable and ssh into the pi.

Comment: Congratulations on finding and fixing the issue! You should "accept" this answer by ticking the check-mark to the left; that will inform other readers that this problem had a solution.

Comment: It doesn't allow me, it gives me a message to "wait until tomorrow"

Comment: Yeah - the system puts a timer on it. Come back in a day or two & you can do it then.

Answer (score 0):

you should go to the raspberry pi website on another device (preferably a computer) and use a microsdxc reader to copy the operating system from the website (there's videos about it).You may have to start over, but that's OK. I know because it's happened to me before.
Best regaurds!